# Lipschitz parameter of tanh function

Tags: real-analysis, machine-learning, lipschitz-functions

## Problem

I am wondering if there is any global Lipschitz parameter for $\tanh(x)=\frac{1-\exp(-2x)}{1+\exp(2x)}$ function. More generally, is there a general way to prove a function is Lipschitz and find its Lipschitz parameter?

Comment: Mean value theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 
$$|\tanh'(x)| = |1- \tanh^2(x)| \leq 1$$
(because $-1 \leq \tanh(x) \leq 1$).

So, by the mean value theorem, $\tanh$ is $1$-Lipschitz.

Comment: Further, we can't improve this because the derivative is $1$ at $x=0$.

Comment: So generally, in order to find the Lipschitz parameter of a function. We just find its derivative and upper bound its absolute value?

Comment: It's the most common way. But note that Lipschitz functions are not always derivable, so this criteria does not necessarily work...